# IIS Central Cert Store - Outbound Traffic

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-8, f5

I have an F5 load-balanced 4-server cluster environment that I'm building, so I'm looking to centralize our certificates to prevent needing to install them all on every server. Windows 2012 / IIS 8 seems to have centralized certificates, but that is only to secure my endpoint in IIS for inbound traffic.

*What about for outbound traffic?* They all will be initiating TLS transactions to external entities, so I need a way to store all these on a single server and have each of the IIS boxes "tap into" that cert store for the private and public keys that are necessary to send that TLS message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's out of IIS scope so you should not expect it comes for free.

Comment: That's what I was thinking also. My question was more around: is it possible at all, such as through another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an [HSM which the F5 will support](https://www.f5.com/pdf/solution-profiles/hardware-security-module-sp.pdf) and IIS also supports a few major vendors (Thales and Safe-Net both have IIS supported HSMs).  They're not cheap from what I remember but that's exactly what you're looking for.

If you don't want to go that route, you can opt for the dirty solution of using the BIG-IP as your cert store and rely on self-signed certs on the IIS pool members.

Inbound:  Incoming traffic terminates on BIG-IP using the valid CA-signed cert SSL Client profile.  BIG-IP re-encrypts to IIS using a generic SSL server profile.  Not pretty but it works.

Outbound:  You would have to use the BIG-IP as the default gateway of the IIS server so you can direct the outbound TLS from BIG-IP instead of IIS directly.

[Devcentral: SSL Acceleration - Can I encrypt outbound traffic](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/ssl-acceleration-can-i-encrypt-outbound-traffic)

Hope this helps.

-Chase